# IPv6 source address selection: can the source address have a smaller scope than the destination address?

Tags: ipv6, rfc

In [RFC 6724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724) section 5 on "Source Address Selection" rule 2 says to "Prefer appropriate scope":

> If Scope(SA) < Scope(SB): If Scope(SA) < Scope(D), then prefer SB and otherwise prefer SA.  Similarly, if Scope(SB) < Scope(SA): If Scope(SB) < Scope(D), then prefer SA and otherwise prefer SB.

This rule does not seem to forbid selecting an address that has a smaller scope than the destination address.

Is this ever valid? If yes, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, consider for example a LAN where global scope addresses are managed by DHCPv6 or manually and where the "A" bit is not set in router advertisements so hosts do not auto-configure global addresses (but do get the routes for on-link addresses). Now consider what happens when a host without a global address pings a global address on the same LAN.